# conversion variable to string not happening

Tags: php

I want to write contents of a variable (i.e. $spider_array) into a .txt file within the same folder where my php script resides. I can run the script, but the array to string conversion isn't happening at all. This is a url harvesting script.

```
part of the script
```

## Get links from $SEED_URL

```
echo "Harvesting Seed URL    \n"; 
$temp_link_array = harvest_links($SEED_URL);
$spider_array = archive_links($spider_array, 0, $temp_link_array);
$output = ($spider_array);
$output .= "";
```

## Write a string to a file

```
 $filename = date('Y_m_d_H_i_s') . '.txt';
 $filepath = dirname(_FILE_);
 file_put_contents ($filepath . '/' . $filename, $output);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing

```
$output = ($spider_array);
$output .= "";
```

To

```
$output = implode("\r\n", $spider_array);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to dump a more complex structure than a simple array you can use [print_r](https://www.php.net/print_r), var_dump, or [var_export](https://www.php.net/var_export) as needed. print_r and var_export have a second parameter that you can set to 'true' if you want to save the result as a string instead of printing to the output buffer; var_dump will only print to the output buffer, to capture the output of that function it would be necessary to use the output control functions.

Example code:

```
<?
$array = array( 1, '2', 'apple' );
$hash = array(
    'a' => 1,
    'b' => 'orange',
    'c' => $array
);

$array_print_r = print_r($array, true);
$hash_print_r = print_r($hash, true);

$array_var_export = var_export($array, true);
$hash_var_export = var_export($hash, true);
?>

########### print_r results ###########

$array:
<?= $array_print_r ?>

$hash:
<?= $hash_print_r ?>


########### var_export results ###########

$array:
<?= $array_var_export ?>

$hash:
<?= $hash_var_export ?>


########### var_dump results ###########

$array:
<?= var_dump($array) ?>

$hash:
<?= var_dump($hash) ?>
```

Example Output:
########### print_r results ###########

```
$array:
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 2
    [2] => apple
)

$hash:
Array
(
    [a] => 1
    [b] => orange
    [c] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => 2
            [2] => apple
        )
)


########### var_export results ###########

$array:
array (
  0 => 1,
  1 => '2',
  2 => 'apple',
)
$hash:
array (
  'a' => 1,
  'b' => 'orange',
  'c' => 
  array (
    0 => 1,
    1 => '2',
    2 => 'apple',
  ),
)

########### var_dump results ###########

$array:
array
  0 => int 1
  1 => string '2' (length=1)
  2 => string 'apple' (length=5)

$hash:
array
  'a' => int 1
  'b' => string 'orange' (length=6)
  'c' => 
    array
      0 => int 1
      1 => string '2' (length=1)
      2 => string 'apple' (length=5)
```